# Typographical styling of UI text in document

Tags: technical-writing, formatting

What are the usual typographical conventions to set off text from the UI in a user manual?

For example, how should I style the text of the label on a button in:

> Press the *Submit* button.

Or styling the text of labels and input values:

> Select *Gluten Free* from the dropdown menu. The enter *I also don't eat soy.* in the *Notes* box.

Comment: I'd suggest graphicdesign.stackexchange.com since it's about typography and text styling.

Comment: It's not about UI design, but about writing about UI design. Graphicdesign.stackexchange.com might be a good place. I'll try there.

Comment: This looks to me like a question about a user manual, not one about a UI.  I'm going to make a minor edit to make it sound less opinion-based.  I think it should be reopened.

Comment: Apparently I was one of the ones who voted to close this, but I was wrong. typographic conventions are most definitely part of technical writing and if we want technical writing questions here, we need to accept these questions. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

The style I see most often in technical writing is that UI labels, like the names of menus, are bold:

> From the **File** menu, choose **Save**.
>
> Click the **Submit** button.

Variable text is usually italic, but this comes up more for command-line interfaces than GUIs:

> git checkout -b *branch-name*

In writing about a GUI you're more likely to *describe* what's needed, which doesn't require styling:

> In the **Path** field, type the name of the top-level directory for the new project.

The Microsoft Style Guide calls for bold for GUI labels and italics for variables, as I've used them here.